# Fix a map in R having unnecessary lines while doing contour plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

Contour plot in r programming language is done it is having some unnecessary horizontal lines over the plot suggest me how to remove those lines

[image]

Here you can see the image has three horizontal lines which are unacceptable for the plot how to remove the lines. ggplot2 tol is used here to plot this image.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example. What code did you use to create this map?